# App script to insert Google Form data into Cloud SQL table (Google Developer's Console)

Tags: javascript, database-connection, google-cloud-sql, google-forms

I am very new to Java and scripts in general, but I am trying to create an app that takes the data from a sites.google website form and places the data into a table within Cloud SQL.

I have successfully created 3 tables (linked with foreign keys) in a database within a Cloud SQL instance on Google's developer console.

The entries in the form correspond to the different headers in the database table, so the data should drop into the appropriate column.

I have tried many of the quickstart and other tutorials within the developer's console documentation links and on the web, but none of them really help me with what I am trying to accomplish..

I have been playing around with code in scripts.google, but haven't really gotten anywhere. Because I am unfamiliar with scripts, I don't know whether I should be using JavaScripts, PHP, python. I've seen tutorials using eclipse and maven but have not been successful/found them helpful.

Hoping someone can steer me in the right direction..
Any feedback or examples I can refer to would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using [Google Sites](https://sites.google.com), then your only option for server side code is Apps Script, and Apps Script uses ONLY JavaScript.  If you wanted to create a site with App Engine, then you could use other server languages, like PHP, Java, and Python.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation?  [JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/)  You can use that service from Apps Script Script Services.

Comment: There are lots of options for storing data.  It depends on how much data and how many users you will have, and what your personal preferences are.  Are you looking for free services?  Do you plan on having hundreds of thousands of users in the next few weeks?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I really appreciate it!
A free service would be ideal, but minimal cost is also acceptable. My free trial on google's Developer Console will run out, and then I'll need to decide if it's worth it pay for the service rather than go for a free option.
I could have a database that resides on google spreadsheets, which I currently have setup. I have a script that allows you to add a new entry to a google spreadsheet, or edit an existing entry. Right now, the database consists of < 700 entries. My only concern is that if the database grows much larger..

Comment: Your ultimate decision should be based on how big this is going to get.  If you stay with Google Sites, then your only server side language option is JavaScript.  That's fine, unless Sites ceases to meet your needs at some point, then you'd have to spend lots of time writing all new code.  Have you looked at Fusion Tables as an option?  I haven't used them, so I can't give an assessment.  I've used Firebase as a database, which you also might want to look at.  I'd probably choose Firebase over Fusion Tables or an SQL database.